# Problem during Ubuntu 22.04 shutdown

Tags: boot, shutdown, openvpn, 22.10

I am facing problem during shutdown of Ubuntu. I use Ubuntu 22.04 with Windows 11. I've been facing this problem for a few days:

[image]

[image]

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Hide. me CLI connection to SERVER.
[FAILED] Failed to start Hide.me CLI connection to US.
"@*@*@*@t 348.0377321 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\CTDP1, AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-3
I 348.0377401
[ 348.0377411 No Local Variables are initialized for Method LIDSP]
[ 348.0377411
348.0377421 No Arguments are initialized for method [IDSP]
1 348.0377421
348.0377431 ACPI Error: Aborting method I_SB. IETM. IDSP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparst
348.0377481 ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB. IETM. _OSC due to previous error (RE_NOT_FOUND) (28221028/psparse [ 379.0067301 systemd-shutdownL11: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes. .
[ 379.0130021 systemd-shutdown[11: Unmounting file systems.
379.0140231 [22314]: Remounting
'/ read-only in with options 'errors-remount-ro
379.0734641 EXT4-fs (nvmeOnip9): re-mounted 3e 44728-0605-43fa-8ac3-b91 fd985812e. Quota mode: none.
[
379.1055491 systemd-shutdownt11: All filesystems unmounted.
379.105630] systemd-shutdown[11: Deactivating swaps.
[
379.105772] systemd-shutdownf11: All swaps deactivated.
379.1058251 systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching loop devices.
379.109205] systemd-shutdown[11: All loop devices detached.
379.109276] systemd-shutdown[1]: Stopping MD devices
379.109421] sustemd-shutdown[1]: All MD devices stopped
[ 379.1094731 sustemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM devices.
379.1095921 systemd-shutdount11: All DM devices detached.
[ 379.1096461 systemd-shutdownE1J: All filesystems, swaps, loop devices, MD devices and DM devices detached.
379.126872] systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices
379.1271043 systemd-shutdounE11: Powering off.
379.1272011 km: exiting hardware virtualization
```

Comment: What is the problem? Your system shuts down neatly. The Hide.me errors don't seem to stop shutting down, and neither does the ACPI Bios error.

Comment: What are your specs? I'm having the same problems with an asus vivobook machine

Comment: @Barbamento its asus zephyrus

Comment: @Jos idk bro thats what  i am trying to figure out.Please help

Comment: @Barbamento does it also not turn on when you place it on sleep modeV